# Creating a Laravel project

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php, invalidargumentexception

I have followed a tutorial on Tuts plus called "Getting started with laravel 4". My `cygwin` and `composer` works fine. When i try installing laravel using the following command:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel
```

i get the following message:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.2.0)
Downloading: 100%

Created project in laravel

[InvalidArgumentException]
Composer could not find the config file: C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in  
the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

I have also tried :
`composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name  --prefer-dist`. but same error .

I have tried looking at the Getting Started section but I am not sure what this file should contain in a laravel project?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The correct base composer. json for a laravel project can be found at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: so, I created the composer.json file and placed it in C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin

but same problem : 
[InvalidArgumentException]
project directory business/is not empty

Comment: Sounds like the directory you are trying to create the project in already exists or already has files in it - you need to install into a fresh/clean directory

Comment: I use Wamp server. whenever I go to localhost, there is no laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

Learn How To Create Basic Laravel Project | Login & Registration | Projects In Laravel | Tilak Singh

Laravel:
https://laravel.com/
Laravel is a free, open-source PHP web framework, created by Taylor Otwell and intended for the development of web applications following the model–view–controller architectural pattern and based on Symfony.

Do following steps:

1. install composer on your system
   Download Link: https://getcomposer.org/download/
2. Run Command:
   composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name

3.after the installation go to project directory and config the .env files

Run Command:
4. composer require laravel/ui
5. php artisan ui vue --auth
6. npm install
7. npm run dev
8. php artisan migrate
9. Run project using: php artisan serve

You can watch videos with step by step:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDEZnNExDro&t=4s

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by entering this composer command:

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname
```

This will install the required files under `projectname` folder